# How do I correctly POST an object to ASP.NET Web API using HttpClient in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've been trying for days to find a proper way to post an object to a Web API controller method using a C# client (specifically, my Windows Forms application). Here is my code for calling the Web API with the object:

```
private async void insertDocument(Document doc)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            Constants.API_ROOT_URI + "Documents/Post", doc);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Document posted successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Document NOT posted successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here my controller POST method in my Web API:

```
// POST api/Documents (INSERT)
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Document doc)
{
    if (doc == null)
    {
        Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
            "Could not read the Document from body");
    }
    bool success = docBL.insertDocumentEntry(doc);
    if (success)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
        "Could not save Document model to database");
}
```

And finally here is my routing template in my `WebApiConfig` file:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

I've tried many ways to do this and properly get my Document object from my C# UI client to my Web API controller method, and every way I have tried has resulted in a "StatusCode 500: Internal Server Error" from my **response variable** in my `insertDocument` method when I debug with a breakpoint. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using Fiddler or other browser tools, what is the raw response from the server?  Do you have possible serialization issues?

Comment: `StatusCode 500: Internal Server Error`means your web api controller is throwing an exception, have you debugged your controller action? If so what is the exception, does it get called at all? If not inspect the response and post the error message.

Comment: @BenRobinson Yes I have tested my controller with a console app in my Web API solution and I still get an internal server error. I do not know why.

Comment: Like @BenRobinson said, you need to debug the controller. Set a breakpoint. Inspect the values. See if an exception is generated in the controller or a filter on the controller or some other step of the processing. That 500 Internal Server Error is your indication that something went wrong on the server, and it's your job to find out what so that you can solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @mason How do I go about debugging the POST method in a controller other than with a console app or Postman? Postman and my web browser both throw a "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." exception when I try to hit Documents/Post. Is my routing off...?

Comment: You need to debug *the server*. Not from the client. Attach VS debugger to your server, set breakpoints, etc.

Comment: Assuming you're hosting the web API in IIS, you may simply just need to enable the HTTP verb GET upon the API IIS app.

Comment: Why are you attempting to send GET requests to POST methods in your debugging tools?

Comment: I realize what is wrong, but I'm not sure what method to use to fix it. I can POST data using Postman but not with my C# code. I seem to not be able to insert object data in my request body. Does anyone know how to properly do this in C#?

Comment: @osnapitsvivz - Can you share the code of your `Document` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong, I'm surprised it took me this long to see the error!

It turns out that I was not filling out all attributes of the object I was passing as a JSON to my Web API. Some objects encapsulated in the head object were not given values so the API registered the JSON as an invalid Document object.

Thanks for all the comments!!!